# How can I smartly extract information from an HTML page?

Tags: parsing, search, full-text-search, machine-learning, nlp

I am building something that can more or less extract key information from an arbitrary web site. For example, if I crawled a McDonalds page and wanted to figure out programatically the opening and closing time of McDonalds, what is an intelligent way to do it?

In a general case, maybe I also want to find out whether McDonalds sells chicken wings, or the address of McDonalds.

What I am thinking is that I will have a specific case for `time`, `wings`, and `address` and have code that is unique for each of those 3 cases.

But I am not sure how I can approach this. I have the sites crawled and HTML and related information parsed into JSON already. My current approach is something like finding the `title` tag and checking if the `title` tag contains key words like `address` or `location`, etc. If the `title` contains those `key words`, then I will look through the current page and identify chunks of content that resemble an address, such as content that are cities or countries or content that has the word `St` or `Street` inside.

I am wondering if there is a better approach to look for key data, and looking for a nicer starting point or bounce some ideas and whatnot. Or even if there are good articles to read about this would be great as well.

Let me know if this is unclear.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

In order to parse such HTML pages you have to have knowlege about their structure. There's no general solution for this problem. Each webpage needs its own solution. However, a good approach would be to ensure the HTML code is valid XML too and then [use XPath to access elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpath) at known positions. Maybe there's even an XPath like solution for standard HTML (which is not always valid xml). This way you can define a set of XPaths for each page which give you the specific elements if they exist.